# 6F00 error when delete an applet from the javacard

Tags: applet, javacard, globalplatform

I use an NXP J2A040 JavaCard(with JCOP 2.4.1, JC 2.2.2, GP 2.1.1., T=1, SCP02) and install a modified ISOApplet(https://github.com/philipWendland/IsoApplet) on the card. The applet can work well when I install it. After running a while the applet always returns 6a86/6a82 when I select files (even 3F00), and the same command worked before. Furthermore, I cannot delete the package or applet from the card. I use the GlobalPlatformPro but it always returns 6F00:

```
>gp --delete 010203040506070809 -d
GlobalPlatformPro 19.06.16-6-g9b08a1a-dirty
Running on Mac OS X 10.15.3 x86_64, Java 11.0.5 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[*] ACS ACR38U
SCardConnect("ACS ACR38U", T=*) -> T=1, 3BFA1300008131FE458031A073BE211367432008
SCardBeginTransaction("ACS ACR38U")
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0094+2) (203ms) 6F5C8408A000000003000000A550734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040255650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E01029F6501FF 9000
[TRACE] GPSession -  [6F]
[TRACE] GPSession -      [84] A000000003000000
[TRACE] GPSession -      [A5]
[TRACE] GPSession -          [73]
[TRACE] GPSession -              [06] 2A864886FC6B01
[TRACE] GPSession -              [60]
[TRACE] GPSession -                  [06] 2A864886FC6B02020101
[TRACE] GPSession -              [63]
[TRACE] GPSession -                  [06] 2A864886FC6B03
[TRACE] GPSession -              [64]
[TRACE] GPSession -                  [06] 2A864886FC6B040255
[TRACE] GPSession -              [65]
[TRACE] GPSession -                  [06] 2B8510864864020103
[TRACE] GPSession -              [66]
[TRACE] GPSession -                  [06] 2B060104012A026E0102
[TRACE] GPSession -          [9F65] FF
[DEBUG] GPSession - Auto-detected ISD: A000000003000000
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[INFO] GPSession - Using card master keys: ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for null
[TRACE] GPSession - Generated host challenge: 57B1A9A20D500076
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 57B1A9A20D500076 00
A<< (0028+2) (34ms) 00000179C4001394AF85FF020054546A7D6BCADB6060020EA77AB757 9000
[DEBUG] GPSession - Host challenge: 57B1A9A20D500076
[DEBUG] GPSession - Card challenge: 0054546A7D6BCADB
[DEBUG] GPSession - Card reports SCP02 with key version 255 (0xFF)
[INFO] GPSession - Diversified card keys: ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for SCP02
[INFO] GPSession - Session keys: ENC=334D1555AC05F46C38E25F6BA7FB6556 MAC=A2EACAD1000FE407B17BB58C54817F49 RMAC=E3D3F305501201FE18AEFB19B3D40E6C, card keys=ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for SCP02
[DEBUG] GPSession - Verified card cryptogram: 6060020EA77AB757
[DEBUG] GPSession - Calculated host cryptogram: BAE8230B5D772802
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 8482010010BAE8230B5D772802
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 BAE8230B5D772802FDFC1525F3B78074
A<< (0000+2) (74ms) 9000
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 84F280020A4F00
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F00C88596C7D2029959 00
A<< (0019+2) (20ms) E3114F08A0000000030000009F700101C5019E 9000
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A000000003000000
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [C5] 9E
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 84F240020A4F00
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24002 0A 4F001C34D3A90627E254 00
A<< (0000+2) (72ms) 6A88
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 84F210020A4F00
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21002 0A 4F008D3BB1EC56F5A430 00
A<< (0235+2) (147ms) E3174F07A00000000353509F7001018408A000000003535041E31F4F07A00000000043499F7001018407A000000000AA058407A000000000AA06E3184F0891560000140300019F70010184089156000014020001E31B4F05315041592E9F700101840E315041592E5359532E4444463031E3154F06A000000333019F7001018407A0000003330101E3434F07A00000000043489F7001018407A000000000AA0A8407A000000000AA048407A000000000AA098407A000000000AA018407A000000000AA028407A000000000AA0BE31C4F090102030405060708099F700101840B0102030405060708090102 9000
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A0000000035350
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000003535041
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A0000000004349
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA05
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA06
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] 9156000014030001
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] 9156000014020001
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] 315041592E
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] 315041592E5359532E4444463031
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A00000033301
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A0000003330101
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A0000000004348
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA0A
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA04
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA09
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA02
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] A000000000AA0B
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] 010203040506070809
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [84] 0102030405060708090102
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 84F220020A4F00
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22002 0A 4F0021E3341FF04ED98C 00
A<< (0105+2) (91ms) E30D4F07A00000000353509F700101E30D4F07A00000000043499F700101E30E4F0891560000140300019F700101E30B4F05315041592E9F700101E30C4F06A000000333019F700101E30D4F07A00000000043489F700101E30F4F090102030405060708099F700101 9000
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A0000000035350
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A0000000004349
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] 9156000014030001
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] 315041592E
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A00000033301
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] A0000000004348
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[TRACE] GPRegistry -  [E3]
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [4F] 010203040506070809
[TRACE] GPRegistry -      [9F70] 01
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: A0000000035350, 1
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: A0000000004349, 1
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: 9156000014030001, 1
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: 315041592E, 1
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: A00000033301, 1
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: A0000000004348, 1
[DEBUG] GPRegistry - Registry already contains PKG: 010203040506070809, 1
[TRACE] DMTokenGenerator - No private key for token generation provided
[TRACE] GPSession - TLV payload:
[TRACE] GPSession -  [4F] 010203040506070809
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 84E40080134F09010203040506070809
A>> T=1 (4+0019) 84E40080 13 4F090102030405060708092FE68F12A06B9A11
A<< (0000+2) (73ms) 6F00
Could not delete AID: 010203040506070809
DELETE failed: 0x6F00
```

Now I cannot install or delete any applet on this card. I searched and tried different ways like add "-deletedeps" to the gp command(which I think is for the old gp tools, the current one doesn't have this parameter). **Is there any other way I can delete this applet from my card or reset my card to blank?**

The possible reason is that I write a trace function that can record the APDU running on the card in the following way. On my test simulator, it doesn't have any bug and it can also work well on the card. Will it cause some dangerous memory leakage or bugs after tracing a lot of records?

```
private byte[] everything =  new byte[256];
private short ins_length = 0;
private boolean startRecord = false;
...
public void process(APDU apdu) {
        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte ins = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];
        byte[] cmdSplit = { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x89};
        short traceLen = 20;

        if(startRecord){
            Util.arrayCopy(buffer, (short) 0, everything, ins_length, traceLen);
            ins_length += traceLen;
            if (ins_length > 230){
                ins_length = 0;
            }
            Util.arrayCopy(cmdSplit, (short) 0, everything, ins_length, (short) 5);
        }
        ...
        if(apdu.isISOInterindustryCLA()) {
            switch (ins) {
                ...
                case INS_START_RECORD: //0x97
                    startRecord = !startRecord;
                    break;
                case INS_CLEAR_TRACE: //0x98
                    everything = new byte[256];
                    ins_length = 0;
                    break;
                case INS_GET_EVERYTHING: //0x99
                    short le = apdu.setOutgoing();
                    byte[] fileData = everything;
                    short maxle = (short)(fileData.length);
                    if(le > maxle) {
                        le = maxle;
                    }
                    apdu.setOutgoingLength(le);
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(fileData, (short) 0, le);
                    break;
                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try with `--delete 010203040506070809 -f`

Comment: Yes. I tried adding -f but still return 6F00.